# activerecord find and update

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Is there a method find_and_update method on ActiveRecord::Base that will basically find a record by it's id and update a given key? This will avoid having to query and then update resulting in 2 queries instead of 1.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

There is an update method in active record, which finds by id and updates attributes. But this will make two sql queries.

```
update(id, attributes)
```

eg

```
 Post.update(params[:id], {:title => 'Hello world'})
```

If you dont want validations to happen, you could use

```
Post.update_all({:title => 'hello1'}, {:id => params[:id]})
```

This will make only one sql query

Answer (score 6):

```
User.where(id: id).update_all(foo: bar)
```

This generates only one query.